# Angular orderBy order of operations

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-orderby

I could not find an answer in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy), if I order by 2 or more params:

```
<tbody ng-reapet="i in list" | orderBy:['m_status', 'm_couter']>
```

What would be the order in orderBy? `m_status` or `m_counter` will be first to `orderBy`? It is hard to test based on 2 or more.

Thanks.

It work fine, this is not a syntax or "how to.." question, my question is how Angular prioritize the array inside `orderBy` - `['m_status', 'm_counter']`.

Comment: I think you copied it wrong, syntax is out, `orderBy` isn't an attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it as below

`<tbody ng-repeat="i in list | orderBy:['m_status', 'm_couter']">`

orderBy filter must be in ng-repeat as below

```
`ng-repeat="some in somelist |orderBy:'name'"`
```

Comment: what? I was not a syntex question...I ask for the order angular the array inside orderBy.

Comment: Here m_status field get the priority ,It defines from left to right for the provided sort fields.

Comment: Thanks, are U sure? any documntation that prove it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JSWorld/Hp4W7/32/ ..here is a link for you,,then u will clear about that,,